# How can I change the name of the index() method in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, methods, python-import

The method I'm talking about

```
list.index()
```

this is my code

```
pt(dt, 'ml', proof.index(ds['pf']), p.index(dt['ps']), d.index(da['dp']), m.index(db['mc']))
```

And I want to write it like this, replacing "index" with "ix"

```
pt(dt, 'ml', proof.ix(ds['pf']), p.ix(dt['ps']), d.ix(da['dp']), m.ix(db['mc']))
```

I tried with

```
import index as ix
```

It did not work (it was kinda obvious tho). Is it even possible to do this? Is there a way to access this method and import it as x, a, b etc?

Is possible to change it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The only way to globally change a method name of a built-in type would be to edit the source code of Python itself, and recompile it.  This would be *utterly insane*, as there's no telling how many places in the standard library use the method with its original name.

Comment: @jasonharper: Well, you don't have to *change* it, you could just make an alias of the original name so either is usable. Still not worth the trouble.

Comment: Oh:(  I thought It would be easier. Anyway thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible for built-ins (user-defined classes can be monkey-patched, built-ins can't, at least not in any reasonable way that doesn't involve terrible hacks at the C layer); you could subclass `list`, define `ix` as an alias of `list.index` and use the subclass for all your types instead of plain `list`, but that's ugly and not worth it.

Closest you could get without requiring changes all over your codebase to use a `list` subclass would be to make an `attrgetter` with a shorter name and use that:

```
from operator import attrgetter

ix = attrgetter('index')  # Done once at global scope early in file and reused later

pt(dt, 'ml', ix(proof)(ds['pf']), ix(p)(dt['ps']), ix(d)(da['dp']), ix(m)(db['mc']))
```

But frankly, that's not particularly nice-looking either (and it'll be slower at runtime to boot, as it disables method call optimizations); just spell out `index` and make your code readable.

Comment: Well, you're right. I'm just new in this and I thought it was a good a idea.

Comment: Technically if I learn C can I rewrite the whole python source code? I mean it's crazy but technically I could?

Comment: @JesserKano. Yes. The guys that write it do just that. It's actually remarkably well written for the most part. With decent C knowledge it would take you just a few minutes to track down the structure where `index` is named and rename it. Recompiling would take a bit longer